# What is wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, homework-and-exercises, reopen

I ask you to reopen my question which has nothing to do with an alleged homework:

[A problem involving adiabatic expansion of ideal gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/772416/a-problem-involving-adiabatic-expansion-of-ideal-gas)

or at least explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: How is this not a “check-my-work” question?

Comment: While it is perfectly reasonable to discuss reopening this questions, I do see that you have accepted an answer, so I am not entirely clear about what you want to achieve by having the question reopened.

Comment: @Buzz If I remember correctly I can change my mind and accept another answer if it seems me to be more convincing or profound. If the question closed there will be no new answers.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero How is this a “check-my-work” question? I did not ask to check my work. I asked about the reason why at least one of the answers is wrong (they can be both wrong anyway).

Comment: Sorry but "My question is: which of these solutions is in error and *what is the source of the error*?" sounds like check-my-work.  So: if this was NOT your intent you need to edit your question so as to clarify conceptually why one law should apply or not, or why one of the assumptions in one of the answer is false, or something along those lines.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have edited my question. Is it ok now or you still have objections?

Comment: better but still borderline IMO.   let’s see what others think…. You already have two answers one of which is accepted so not sure what good (or bad) it is to keep the question closed…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Would you vote for re-opening if I unaccept the answer?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Or maybe I should just ask the edited version of the question again as it cannot be anymore suspected to be  a "homework" or “check-my-work” question?

Comment: why don’t you just let it happen…I dunno if it should be re-opened or not.  It’s time for others to express their opinions.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The option to ask the question again is given me by closing the question. If we together find what was wrong with the question and formulate it in a correct way, so that no suspicion about "homework" or "check-my-work" arises, it will help also the future users which just like me love physics to formulate their question. So what is still wrong with my question?

Comment: I've reworded the end of your question.  I *do not* like doing this because it may mean previous answers are now out of context, but the question is closed so it's a mitigating circumstance: at least it's better than asking anew a variation of the same question.  Given the new version you may consider if the accepted answer is still appropriate.   *If you think my edits are too drastic or does not reflect what you had in mind please consider a roll-back.*